# Can not load "webpack"!Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema

Tags: angular, webpack, karma-runner

I caught this error when testing `Angular`.

> Can not load "webpack"! WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid
>   configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a
>   configuration object that does not match the API schema.

```
+-- @angular/cli@1.0.1
+-- angular@1.6.4
+-- angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.28.3
+-- webpack@2.5.0
`-- webpack-dev-server@2.4.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your last line:

```
`-- webpack-dev-server@2.4.4
```

to:

```
+-- webpack-dev-server@2.4.4
```

Does that work?